# What is the linguistic term for "to" in front of an infinitive?

Tags: terminology

I know that "to" can be a preposition and an adverb but what is the term for it in front of an infinitive?

Comment: I would call it an infinitive marker.

Comment: Thank you, do you know of any credible online resource that can back this term up? I searched the internet and could not find anything which is why I asked the question here.

Comment: umm, actually don't have any. I just call it *infinitive marker* because it marks infinitive. I don't think its name is important, though. Sometimes we call it a subordinator when it introduces a subordinate clause.

Comment: If you Google "infinitive marker" you will find scores of references. Other grammarians categorize this *to* as a "subordinator".

Comment: Check [*to*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to_1): in the "to used before the base form of a verb" section.

Comment: Maybe StoneyB should post it as an answer, this was helpful.

Comment: @StoneyB Many grammarians use *subordinator* for the PoS and *Marker* for the syntactic function.

Answer (score 4):

It is referred to in many different ways. Because a lot of people aren't sure what part of speech it is, it is often just called *infinitival to*. It is also sometimes referred to as the *infinitival particle*.

For many modern grammarians, *to* is a **subordinator** with the syntactic function of marking infinitival verb phrases as subordinate (and therefore also termed a **Marker** - but note that *Marker* is a syntactic function and not a part of speech).

Because historically infinitival *to* was originally a **preposition**, some dictionaries list it as a preposition. However, very few modern grammarians or linguists think that infinitival *to*  is a preposition in modern English.

Other grammarians argue that *to* is a unique word that doesn't belong to any other part of speech. They say that it is **syncategorematic**.

However, the most convincing argument is that infinitival *to* is a non-finite (in other words tenseless) **auxiliary verb**. This is what has been argued by linguists such as Geoffrey K Pullum.

---

<sup>**Note for linguistics students:**</sup>

<sup>If you are a linguist, or a linguistics students, you can read a linguistics paper about why infinitival *to* is a non-finite auxiliary verb [here](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/levine.1/publications/Levine_auxiliary_to.pdf). It's quite tough, but interesting.</sup>

Comment: I think Levin's paper is far too heavy for ELL. The symbols alone  will be a mystery to most. As I said before, many will consider the arguments therein arcane. Okay for Stack Linguistics, though, although I suspect that most people have made up their mind and moved on.

Comment: @BillJ Noted. Is that any better?

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting to observe that Dictionaries present different definitions, but the majority has explained it under title (label) of **preposition**.

Cambridge: [Preposition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to): used before a verb to show that it is in the infinitive.

Oxford: [Infinitive Marker](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to): Used with the base form of a verb to indicate that the verb is in the infinitive.

M.Webster: [Preposition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to): used as a function word to indicate that the following verb is an infinitive.

The A.H.: [Preposition](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=to): Used before a verb to indicate the infinitive.

Answer (score 0):

The "to" that introduces infinitival clauses belongs to the category (part of speech) **subordinator** and its function is **marker**.

Comment: That's a very contentious answer. *To* is a non-finite auxiliary verb! :D

Comment: @AraucariaMan Defective? :D

Comment: @AraucariaMan I know that Pullum says that, but I prefer Huddleston's analysis, which is less contentious and more widely accepted. To justify it being an aux verb would be pointless and the explanation arcane. Not for ELL methinks.

Comment: @BillJ As a teacher, I've been using that explanation for yonks - and students actually find it very useful. It stops them saying things like *Yes, I want* and so forth. So my thinking is that it probably makes intuitive sense as long as you haven't been thinking of it as something else all along.

Comment: @Man_From_India Yes, because it has no tensed forms. :D

Comment: @AraucariaMan Didn't we look at this a year or so back?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, indeed. That's what prompted your email to GKP about it!